# How to show a dialog or popup from .net core without javascript

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to create a .NET CORE application without using javascript at all and I am struggling to show dialogs to perform various crud operation, I want to call a controller action that will fill the dialog data and then show it to the user, without ever needing to use ajax or jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to show a dialog or popup from .net core without javascript

You could use CSS style to show the dialog or popup, code like this:

CSS style:

```
<style>
    /* popups without javascript */

    /* showing popup background */
    a.popup:target {
        display: block;
    }

        /* showing popup */
        a.popup:target + div.popup {
            display: block;
        }

    /* popup target anchor and background */
    a.popup {
        /* background is initially hidden */
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 3; /* anything, really, but bigger than other elements on the page */
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
        cursor: default;
    }

    /* popup window */
    div.popup {
        /* popup window is initially hidden */
        display: none;
        background: white; /* choose your color; */
        width: 640px; /* width */
        height: 480px; /* height */
        position: fixed;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -320px; /* = -width / 2 */
        margin-top: -240px; /* = -height / 2 */
        z-index: 4; /* z-index of popup backgroung + 1 */
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

        /* links to close popup */
        div.popup > a.close {
            color: white;
            position: absolute;
            font-weight: bold;
            right: 10px;
        }

            div.popup > a.close.word {
                top: 100%;
                margin-top: 5px;
            }

            div.popup > a.close.x {
                bottom: 100%;
                margin-bottom: 5px;
            }
</style>
```

Html Content:

```
<h1>Popup without javascript demo</h1>
<p><a href="#my_popup">Open popup</a></p>
<p>HTML visible body ends here</p>

<!--
Popup: the key is that id of <a> tag below is the same as href of <a> tag above
- that's what opens popup
<a> below serves several purposes:
    1) popup background covering the whole window,
    2) anchor to show popup when #my_popup is in URL,
    3) link to close popup - if you click the background popup disappears
-->
<a id="my_popup" href="#" class="popup"></a>
<div class="popup">
    <h3>My popup heading</h3>
    <p>Popup content</p>
    <a class="close x" href="#">x</a>
    <a class="close word" href="#">Close</a>
</div>
```

The result like this:

[image]

Code from [this link](https://gist.github.com/epoberezkin/4722580), and you could also refer [this sample](https://codepen.io/sahil4test/pen/xERYvX).

> I am struggling to show dialogs to perform various crud operation, I
> want to call a controller action that will fill the dialog data and
> then show it to the user, without ever needing to use ajax or jquery

Since you don't want to use JQuery or Ajax, the above popup content should be populated when the page load, and when executing the CURD operations, you have to refresh the whole page. To implement partial view refreshes the popup content, you have to use JQuery and Ajax.